# Tagging data based on their rolling quarters in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pivot

Really appreciate your help on this.

I have the below dataset as,

| Emp | Month_Dates | Report_Quarter | Sub | Un-Sub1 | Un-Sub2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Emp1 | 08/01/2022 | Q3-2022 | 0 | 1 | 0 |  |
| Emp1 | 01/01/2022 | Q1-2022 | 0 | 0 | 1 |  |
| Emp1 | 12/01/2021 | Q4-2021 | 0 | 1 | 0 |  |
| Emp1 | 05/01/2021 | Q2-2021 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

From this, I have created a rolling 4-quarter from Month_Dates column. In this, dataset, the rolling quarter starts from Q3-2022 and rolls till Q4-2021 and are marked as 1Q (Q3-2022), 2Q (Q2-2022), 3Q (Q1-2022), 4Q (Q4-2021). Now, I need to tag the Sub and NonSub values based on their quarter. Like,

- Q3-2022 has 1 UnSub and 0 Sub. So 1 has to be tagged in 1Q_Unsub and 0 has to be tagged in 1Q_Sub
- There is no Q2-2022 in above dataset. So 0 in 2Q_UnSub and 0 in 2Q_Sub
- Q1-2022 has 1 UnSub and 0 Sub. So 1 in 3Q_UnSub and 0 in 3Q_Sub
- Q4-2021 has 1 UnSub and 0 Sub. So 1 in 4Q_UnSub and 0 in 4Q_Sub

The expected output is,

| 1Q | 2Q | 3Q | 4Q | 1Q_UnSub | 2Q_UnSub | 3Q_UnSub | 4Q_UnSub | 1Q_Sub | 2Q_Sub | 3Q_Sub | 4_Sub |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Q322 | Q222 | Q122 | Q421 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Can you please advise on how this can be achieved via pyspark/sql?

Thanks!

I thought of using pivot but not sure whether it'll suit for this scenario.